# How do I prove that an element g of order $2$ (only one) in a group is central ($gh=hg$ for all $h$)?

Tags: group-theory

I'm not advancing in this exercise. Let $G$ be a group. There only exists one element $g \in G$ with $ord(g)=2$. I should proof that $g$ is central, that means $gh=hg$ for all $h \in G$.

Comment: The conjugate of g is also an element of order n

Comment: i thought the conjugate of g is g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same starting point, but a little shorter (no calculation):

Conjugates $hgh^{-1}$  are images of $g$ by an inner *automorphism*. A group isomorphism does not change the order of an element.  As there is only one element of order $2$, we have $$hgh^{-1}=g,\enspace\text{i.e.}\enspace hg=gh\enspace \text{for all}\; h.$$

Answer (score 3):

Choose $h\in G$ and consider the element $hgh^{-1}$. Note that $$hgh^{-1}hgh^{-1}=hggh^{-1}=hh^{-1}=1$$
since $g$ has order $2$. Hence $hgh^{-1}$ has either order $1$ or $2$. But if $hgh^{-1}$ would have order $1$, then $hgh^{-1}=1$, which implies $g=1$. This is not possible since $g$ has order $2$. So $hgh^{-1}$ must have order $2$. Since $g$ is the only element with order $2$, it follows that $$hgh^{-1}=g,$$ hence $$hg=gh.$$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $g^2=1$ and $g\neq1$. Note that for any $h\in G$
$$
(h^{-1}gh)^2=h^{-1}g^2h=h^{-1}1h=1
$$
so $h^{-1}gh$ is also of order $2$. But by the uniqueness of $g$, we must conclude that $h^{-1}gh=g$, that is $gh=hg$ QED